# Describe the cone generated by vectors $(1,0,0,1), (0,2,3,4), (0,0,3,1), (1,3,2,4), (2,4,6,4)$ by its irredundant linear inequalities.

Tags: polyhedra, convex-cone

I'm really not sure on how to tackle this. I have tried considering all matrices comprised of three of the five vectors -- as rows -- and row reducing them, but that hasn't really lead anywhere (so far).

I know that the cone consists of all conic combinations of the generating vectors. I am unsure of how to glean its irredundant inequalities.

Comment: Vector number 4 is the arithmetic mean of vectors number 2 and 5. So this vector is redundant. It seems that 4 remaining vectors are irredundant.

Comment: @BazyliZuczek Maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment, but it seems the result of the arithmetic mean of those two vectors would be (1, 3, 4.5, 4), and not vector 3.

Comment: You are right, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

We have $5$ points $A,B,C,D,E,$ such that every $4$ points determine an affine hyperplane. Let's describe the one corresponding to $A,B,C$ and $D,$ i.e. we discard $E.$ We form $3$ vectors $v=\vec{AB},u=\vec{AC},w= \vec{AD}.$  The equation of the hyperplane is given by
$$\begin{vmatrix} {\bf x_1} & \bf{x_2} & \bf x_3 & \bf x_4\\
u_1 & u_2 & u_3 & u_4 \\ 
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & v_4 \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & w_4
\end{vmatrix}=0,$$ while the affine hyperplane is described by  $$\begin{vmatrix} {\bf x_1} & \bf{x_2} & \bf x_3 & \bf x_4\\
u_1 & u_2 & u_3 & u_4 \\ 
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & v_4 \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & w_4
\end{vmatrix} =\begin{vmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4\\
u_1 & u_2 & u_3 & u_4 \\ 
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & v_4 \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & w_4
\end{vmatrix}=:\Delta_A,$$ where $A=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4).$
Then for $E=(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$  we calculate the determinant
$$  \Delta_E:=\begin{vmatrix} e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & e_4\\
u_1 & u_2 & u_3 & u_4 \\ 
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & v_4 \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & w_4
\end{vmatrix}.$$
If $\Delta_E>\Delta_A,$ one of the inequalities describing the region is of the form
$$\begin{vmatrix} {\bf x_1} & \bf{x_2} & \bf x_3 & \bf x_4\\
u_1 & u_2 & u_3 & u_4 \\ 
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & v_4 \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & w_4
\end{vmatrix}\ge \begin{vmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4\\
u_1 & u_2 & u_3 & u_4 \\ 
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & v_4 \\
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & w_4
\end{vmatrix}.$$
We repeat that procedure for $4$ remaining cases and obtain $5$ inequalities describing the region.